# How do I call get_post_meta properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit confused, but if I call `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "event", $single = true);` it returns the value for that key, but if I call it this way:

```
$event_page_meta = "event";


function isEvent()
{
    return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $event_page_meta, $single = true);
}
```

it returns Array of all meta. I'm rather unexperienced php-developer (mostly python), but I cannot see any difference between those two calls.

Can you explain why I cannot extract that key to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The third argument for get_post_meta should be true or false, not a variable assignment. Just write `true`.
2. $event_page_meta is not in scope within the function, you either need to pass it in as an argument or make it global.

Ether:

```
function isEvent($event_page_meta) {
    return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $event_page_meta, true);
}

//somewhere else
$something = isEvent($event_page_meta);
```

Or:

```
function isEvent() {
    global $event_page_meta;
    return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $event_page_meta, true);
}
```

...this assumes $event_page_meta contains the name of the metadata key you want to retrieve. I am not sure why it's in a variable and not just a string in your function call.

Comment: yes! great! I thing global is better for my case as I want to have some global settings across the site.

Comment: Using global variables usually means you've written some poorly designed code.

Comment: OK. May you can tell me the better design for such global constants? Using them as global ones seems to be a good and pretty straightforward idea? I really want to know - e.g. in python I'd create a constants.py module where would store all such variables.

Comment: If they are constants, they should be constants, not variables. If they are not constants, you should pass them to the function as an argument, or they should be member variables of some object whose methods operate on them. http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php